# Ruta de Laravel 5.5 con "where"

Tags: php, laravel

Hola estoy empezando a pasar mi web a Laravel y me encuentro con un problema en una ruta con clausula ***where*** que tiene una pequeña *regex*

```
Route::get('/{region}/leader/{bracket}', 'LeaderController')
        ->where(['region' => '(en|us)', 'bracket' => '(2v2|3v3|rbg)']);
```

Os dejo la salida del test:

```
.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F.                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 202 ms, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\LeaderControllerTest::its_load_leader_eu_2v2
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\laragon\www\murlocmate\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:78
C:\laragon\www\murlocmate\tests\Feature\LeaderControllerTest.php:14

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

Código del test:

```
public function its_load_leader_eu_2v2()
    {
        $this->get('/eu/leader/2v2')
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertSee('eu 2v2');
    }
```

Comment: ¿Versión de Laravel?

Comment: me la baje hoy con laragon, supongo que la ultima

Comment: Puedes hacer un **artisan -v** o **php artisan -v** en la consola para averiguarlo o bien consultar el fichero **composer.json**. No conozco *laragon*. Añadir la versión puede ser pertinente para encontrar una solución ya que cambian cosas.

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.5.19

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no se porque no funciona ese where en el route, al final tuve que añadir la clausula al archivo RouteServiceProvides.php de la carpeta Providers, añadi lo siguiente:

```
public function boot()
    {
        //
        Route::pattern('region', '(eu|us)');
        Route::pattern('bracket', '(2v2|3v3|rbg)');

        parent::boot();
    }
```